# Input file validation with knockout JS and file API

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am new to knockout js and trying to write custom validation for file input from client side using knockout JS and file API. The main aim is to validate the file extension and file size, and clear the file input path should validation error occur.

Below is the code being done using pure javascript. Appreciate if someone could lend a hand.

```js
function FileAPIViewModel() {
  var self = this;
}

ko.applyBindings(new FileAPIViewModel());

$('#i_file').change( function() {
    //check whether browser fully supports all File API
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
    {
        //get the file size and file type from file input field
        var fsize = $('#i_file')[0].files[0].size;
        var ftype = $('#i_file')[0].files[0].type;
        
        if(fsize>10)
        {
            alert(fsize +" bites\nToo big!");
            $('#i_file').val('');
        }
      
       switch(ftype)
        {
            case 'image/png':
            case 'image/gif':
                break;
            default:
                alert('Unsupported File!');
                $('#i_file').val('');
        }
    }else{
        alert("Please upgrade your browser, because your current browser lacks some new features we need!");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" input="" id="i_file" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="i_submit" />
```

Comment: tough you can achieve with simple `change event` in ko way . try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26692/ . let us know

Comment: @supercool thanks for the feedback. But i am trying to make use of knockout.validation plugin (custom validation rules) for achieving this validation, in which it is reusable and the error message is parsed into the ValidationMessage attribute and not simply alert box.

Comment: ok do you have multiple input type `file` controls ? on you page you trying to apply validation on those

Comment: @supercool the current situation that i am dealing with is maximum one file per upload

Comment: alright you can check this which works for one but not for multiple http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/ccL3dtym/ . if you want to show different validation messages you make use of creating multiple validators i.e chaining kind of .

Comment: For multiple as i am using the same observable for different controls creating a mutual dependent issue http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/ccL3dtym/2/ . there will be a better way to deal it . i'll try once i get sometime

Comment: @supercool what if i one to specific the file type/file size in parameter at ko.observable().extend({})?

Comment: i suggest you have a look at validation docs in github anyways check here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/ccL3dtym/3/ . good luck

Comment: Here's a little mod to @supercool's fiddle that gives you messages based on which validation check failed. http://jsfiddle.net/ccL3dtym/4/

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a custom jquery validator for this.

```
$.validator.addMethod("filesize", function (value, element, params) {

//20000000

var ext = value.substr(value.length - 4);

//If  there is no file
if (value === "") {
    return false;
}
//check extension
if (ext !== null) {
    if (ext !== ".pdf") {
        return false;
    }
}
//check file size
if(element.files[0] != null){
    if (element.files[0].size > 20000000) {
        return false;
    }
}   
return true;

}, 'Must Upload A Valid PDF Under 20MB');
```

Then add rule to your input(s) which I believe is i_file

```
$('[id^="i_file"]').each(function () {

    $(this).rules('add', {

        filesize: true

    });
});
```